# Alfresco and LDAP full integration

Tags: integration, alfresco, alfresco-share

Is it possible to make an integration between Alfresco and LDAP to manage groups, users and permissions? 
I mean, alfresco groups must be managed with its own set of permissions? Currently I have a LDAP repository to allow authentication, but it is a lot of work to maintain users and groups across multiple systems.
In other words, can i make a full integration between these two environments easily and without modifying the core of alfresco?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no.

IMHO, externally managed users, groups and authentication are already the maximum to make sense of. Even then, a part of authorities (users / groups) will still be created locally in alfreco when you start using share sites and invite external people. Sure, this could technically be changed, but alfresco writing to LDAP opens a new can of worms. The default LDAP read/sync approach should not cause sigificant extra efforts.

Authorization data, such als roles (which can easily be confused with groups) and permissions and their semantics are highly dependent on application (alfresco). It does not make sense to manage them in an external system that has no clue.